Resizing header font overflows from the box
I'm somewhat new to css and I've been trying to create a header with the website title sitting in the middle of it. Only thing is when I try to make the font bigger it moves down and eventually overflows out of the header box. I want to keep it contained within but I have no idea how.
This is what I have so far:
header {
    background-color: #ffd7f5;
    color: #fe8fd3;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 47px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 110px;
    z-index: 5;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 5px dashed #fe8fd3;
}

and this is the html:
<body>
        <header>
            <h1>Header Title</h1>
        </header>
</body>


Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The main issue with your CSS code is that you have set a fixed value of 110px for the height property of the header element. If the content of the header element is taller than 110px, then it will overflow outside of the element. This is happening for me even with default font size in Firefox on desktop Windows as the h1 element has a total height of 108px + 63px top margin + 63px bottom margin = 234px. Note that top and bottom margins for the h1 element are a browser default which you need to override using CSS if you wish to customize them.
To fix this, simply remove the height property from the header CSS declaration: this will allow the header to automatically adjust its height to its content. To control the height of the header, make sure that you control the height of what it contains.
I've also made a few extra improvements:

set the h1's margin to 0 to override default browser style and make the h1 as small as possible
added code for Universal Box Sizing with Inheritance and reset the body element's margin and padding properties to 0 to make sure that your header is well centered and to prevent its right border from disappearing outside of the screen.

Hope this helps!


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Centered Header</title>
    <style>
        /* https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/#aa-universal-box-sizing-with-inheritance */
        html {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        *, *:before, *:after {
            box-sizing: inherit;
        }
        /* Reset body spacing */
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        /* Custom styles */
        header {
            background-color: #ffd7f5;
            border-radius: 5px;
            border: 5px dashed #fe8fd3;
            color: #fe8fd3;
            font-size: 47px;
            margin: auto;
            position: fixed;
            text-align: center;
            top: 0;
            width: 100%;
            z-index: 5;
        }
        /* Reset h1 spacing */
        header h1 {
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Website Title</h1>
    </header>
</body>
</html>




H1 tag is taking default margin, you need to set it up. Just add the below css code in your style and it will work fine.
header h1{margin:0;padding:0;}


Can you explain why this would help - it just gives a little more room, but eventually, on a narrow viewport, the text will still be too big for the header.

Narrow viewport can be easily adjusted by media queries



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* Header styles */
header {
    background-color: #ffd7f5;
    color: #fe8fd3;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 47px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 110px;
    z-index: 5;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 5px dashed #fe8fd3;
    display: flex; /* Enables flexbox (Add this) */
    align-items: center; /* Centers content vertically (Add this) */
    justify-content: center; /* Centers content horizontally (Add this) */
}

/* Title styles */
header h1 {
    font-size: 36px; /* Adjust font size as needed */
    margin: 0; /* Removes default margins */
    line-height: 1.2; /* Ensures proper spacing within the text */
}
</style>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Centered Header</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Website Title</h1>
    </header>
</body>
</html>



I changed your code little bit as above. Try it.

Your HTML is invalid with two <head> tags.

Answers are more useful if they contain an explanation of what changes were made to the code and why. You can edit your answer to include an explanation. Also consider making the code into a runnable snippet so it can be easily checked by others. Thanks.

Thank you for the comment. I have added this code to runnable snippet
